# HeadlessException on Windows 10 machine

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to show a message using Swing but when I create it I receive this error message:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.HeadlessException
>       at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
>       at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:536)
>       at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:420)
>       at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:385)
>       at javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.(SwingUtilities.java:1758)
>       at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:1833)
>       at javax.swing.JOptionPane.getRootFrame(JOptionPane.java:1696)
>       at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:863)
>       at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:666)
>       at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:637)
>       at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:608)
>       at sintel.onetouch.online.controle.ControlePrincipal$1.run(ControlePrincipal.java:272)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

This is a chunk of the code:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {


            List<Evento> events = null;

            while(true)
            {
                try
                {
                    if(codigoUltimoEvento <= 0)
                    {
                        codigoUltimoEvento = controleAcessoDB.buscaCodigoUltimoEvento();

                        System.out.println("codigo ultimo evento:" + codigoUltimoEvento);
                    }

                    events = controleAcessoDB.listaEvento(codigoUltimoEvento);

                    if (events.size() > 0)
                    {
                        Evento evento = events.get(events.size() - 1);
                        codigoUltimoEvento = evento.getCodigoEvento();

                        System.out.println("codigo ultimo evento novo:" + codigoUltimoEvento);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            sleep(4000);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException ex)
                        {
                            GerenciadorLog.logException(ex);
                            Logger.getLogger(ControlePrincipal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }

                        continue;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    GerenciadorLog.logException(ex);
                    events = null;
                }

                if(events != null)
                {
                    System.out.println("//eventos != null");

                    //TODO porque i = 1?
                    int i = 1;

                    for (Evento evento : events)
                    {
                        i = ++i;

                        if(evento.getEquipamento().getTipoComunicacao() != ETipoComunicacao.IP_UDP)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (((evento.getTipoEvento() == ETipoEvento.ACESSO_EMERGENCIA) || evento.getTipoEvento() == ETipoEvento.SAIDA_EMERGENCIA))
                        {
                            String usarSom = GerenciadorProperties.getProperty("som.ativo");

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Eggs are not supposed to be green.");
                        }
                    }
                }

                try
                {
                    sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex)
                {
                    GerenciadorLog.logException(ex);
                    Logger.getLogger(ControlePrincipal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

I'm running it on a Windows 10 machine, on netbeans IDE.

I already tried to use JavaFX instead Swing but it gives me other problems.
I tried to execute on a new thread, using swing worker like the code above.

Comment: We have no idea what your custom classes do, so we can't really help. I would suggest you should NOT have a `while (true)` loop with a `Thread.sleep()` statement. This will cause the GUI to freeze since you are telling the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) to sleep. I suggest you download the `DialogDemo` code from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) and test it to see if you have problems. You should also read another section from the tutorial on `Concurrency in Swing` to understand the EDT.

Comment: Have you resolved this problem?